# powershell - write to rtf with text decoration

Tags: powershell

I am trying to save information to a .rtf log file. The goal is to have three messages - good, warning, and bad - and a different color (green, yellow, red) for each one. I have used powershell to save richtextbox items to rtf and it saves the text decorations as well. However, this particular script has no GUI, only console, and I can't find a way to write to rtf and save the text colors. Is there a way? Sample script below:

```
$outFile = "E:\results.rtf"
$message = "This is not in compliance"
Write-Host $message -ForegroundColor "red" 
$message | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append #can I set a color here?
```

Comment: RTF is a data format for saving and sharing documents, not a markup language; it is not intended for intuitive and easy typing. However, you could apply [Rich Text Format (RTF) Specification](https://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm) (uncommendable).